# Hibernate query doesn't return a result

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, oracle10g, sessionfactory

I am stuck with an error. It seems that the database query returns a null value even that the value and the query that i am using are correct.

```
public Ods_Gis_Actel getById(String id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Ods_Gis_Actel a = (Ods_Gis_Actel) session.get(Ods_Gis_Actel.class,new String(id));
    return a;
}
```

(Log4j showing the right query in the console, and i am sure that the line i am searching exist in the table).

The query getAll() that works fine, **so i think that means that the mapping is correct.**
can it be the hibernate.util ?

public class HibernateUtil {
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

```
static {
    try {
        // Creation of SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

// public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

thanks,

Comment: You are only beginning transaction, where does it ends?

Comment: You call `session.beginTransaction();` inside `getById` method. Where do you ending this transaction?

Comment: it ends when i get the result, no?

Comment: No, https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions.

Comment: so i need to : session.flush(); session.close();  This is it?

Comment: that's not the solution..

Comment: Did you try copying the query from Log4j console and running it in another database tool? Sometimes, value ('id' in your case) may have an extra space at the end or beginning?

Comment: Just read carefully about sessions and transactions.

Comment: it is not an insert or delect query to do a : transaction.commit  ??

Comment: yes i have Mr alexandre, and that didn't work